# error: el campo ‘GSEAL’ se declaró como una función

Tags: c, compilar, gcc, gtk

Tengo este error al usar un *include* del *GTK*:

```
/usr/include/gtk/gtkaccelgroup.h:90:23: error: el campo ‘GSEAL’ se declaró como una función
   90 |   guint               GSEAL (lock_count);
      |                       ^~~~~
```

Código del archivo ***gtkaccelgroup.h***:

```
/**
 * GtkAccelGroup:
 * 
 * An object representing and maintaining a group of accelerators.
 */
struct _GtkAccelGroup
{
  GObject             parent;

  guint               GSEAL (lock_count);
  GdkModifierType     GSEAL (modifier_mask);
  GSList             *GSEAL (acceleratables);
  guint               GSEAL (n_accels);
  GtkAccelGroupEntry *GSEAL (priv_accels);
};
```

Comando para compilar:

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../..   -g -Wall -g -c GzIO.c
```

Trazado de compilación:

```
En el fichero incluido desde /usr/include/gtk/gtkwindow.h:35,
                 desde /usr/include/gtk/gtkdialog.h:35,
                 desde /usr/include/gtk/gtkaboutdialog.h:32,
                 desde /usr/include/gtk/gtk.h:33,
```

Archivo: ***/usr/include/gtk/gtkwindow.h:35***

```
#include <gtk/gtkaccelgroup.h>
```

Archivo: ***/usr/include/gtk/gtkdialog.h:35***

```
#include <gtk/gtkwindow.h>
```

Archivo: ***/usr/include/gtk/gtkaboutdialog.h:32***

```
#include <gtk/gtkdialog.h>
```

Archivo: ***/usr/include/gtk/gtk.h:33***

```
#include <gtk/gtkaboutdialog.h>
```

¿Cómo cambio esta función que pueda compilar?

Comment: Por lo que veo GSEAL debe estar  definida como una macro #define GSEAL porque de lo contrario todo el struct estuviera errado. No debes tener el include donde se define GSEAL. Verifica si en  alguno de los include gtk*.h que pones se encuentra el #define GSEAL. Si lo encuientras entonces debe  estar condicionada, de lo contrario, te falta un include gtk*.h o  los includes gtk*.h no están en el orden adecuado.   Quizá se encuentre en el gtk.h si está en éste entonces  debes poner este include antes de los demás.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Perfecto, con eso lo solucioné.

Comment: Ok. En tu respuesta deberías incluir en que  parte  lo definiste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionarlo hay que definir `GSEAL` de la siguiente manera:

```
#ifndef __GTK_ACCEL_GROUP_H__
#define __GTK_ACCEL_GROUP_H__

#define GSEAL(ident)      _g_sealed__ ## ident
```

Se define luego del `ifndef`.